# How to verify a particular text in response body using postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

Response Body

```
{
    "message": "Hi I am 'lakshmi' from 'India'"
}
```

The text `lakshmi` is provided in pre-request script and I need to verify the same in the response.
I don't want to verify like this below

```
Var message = "Hi I am 'lakshmi' from 'India'"
```

Since I mentioned `lakshmi` as global variable how do I verify in the test like

```
Hi I am "{{name}}" from 'India'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Test scripts](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-scripts/) from Postman. Check also those [examples](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-examples/)

This code should work

```
pm.test("Status test", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

var expectedValue  = pm.environment.get("lakshmi");
pm.test("Body contains variable", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(expectedValue);
});

// IF YOU WANT TO CHECK THE WHOLE SENTENCE
var expectedValue  = "Hi I am '" + pm.environment.get("lakshmi") + "' from 'India";
pm.test("Body contains variable", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.body(expectedValue);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
let name = pm.globals.get("name"),
    jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Name is correct in the response", () => {
    pm.expect(jsonData.message).to.equal(`Hi I am ${name} from 'India'`)
})
```

Or

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test("Name is correct in the response", () => {
    pm.expect(jsonData.message).to.equal(`Hi I am ${pm.variables.replaceIn('{{name}}')} from 'India'`)
})
```